# What is the Purpose of a "?" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

What purpose does the question mark serve in the following code snippet:

```
Template.lists.selected = function () {
    return Session.equals('list_id', this._id) ? 'selected' : '';
};
```

Comment: It's JavaScript's Conditional operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: @Matt You are right, but it is not specifically for javascript.

Comment: @sdespont Thank you, I was about to add that this operator was unique to JavaScript and no other language has it, but then your comment saved me from that embarrassment. (Actually I mentioned it so that the OP would know that it is not part of handlebars or meteor, but rather the JavaScript language itself...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's known as a ternary operator in a number of languages. It's a shortcut for a full-on `if-then` statement.

Instead of writing this:

```
Template.lists.selected = function () {
   if(Session.equals('list_id', this._id)) {
      return 'selected';
   }
   else {
      return '';
   }
};
```

You do this:

```
Template.lists.selected = function () {
   return Session.equals('list_id', this._id) ? 'selected' : '';
};
```

The `if` return is immediately after the question mark; the `else` return is after the colon.

Comment: Do you know if there is a shortcut to do this inside the template directly? Something like {{#tertiary true,'iftrue','iffalse'}}

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about meteor. This is a straight-on programming construct.

Comment: Ya I would like to do it inside the handlebars template, but that would involve a custom block helper.  So I'll figure something out